# php private array access from member function

Tags: php, class

When I run this code, I get only "in constructor" being printed out.

Why am I not seeing the array being printed out?

Apache log shows no errors. PHP syntax checkers show no errors.

```
<?php
//---- User Class ----      
class User {
    private $list;

    function __construct() { 
        echo "in constructor";
        $this->$list = array(1, 2, 5);
        }

    function printAll() {
        print_r($this->$list);
    }

}   // end Class  

$foo = new User(); 
$foo->printAll();
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a $ to much, try this

When I run this code, I get only "in constructor" being printed out.

Why am I not seeing the array being printed out?

Apache log shows no errors. PHP syntax checkers show no errors.

```
class User {
    private $list;

    function __construct() { 
        echo "in constructor";
        $this->list = array(1, 2, 5);
        }

    function printAll() {
        print_r($this->list);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should make the function public? public function printAll(){} (this is a wild guess)

Comment: Missing a closing bracket on `printAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes $this->varname 
     is the proper syntax which we mix up some times.

```
 class Cname {
    var $name;

     function setName($nam)
     {
         $this -> name = $nam;
     }
  }
```